# sharepoint datetime control does not display value on page load

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint Datetime control in one of my asp.net custom pages. The problem is that I am trying to display the value from the sharepoint field in the datetime control, but it does not display it on page load. If I refresh the page then it displays it.

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtdueDate" DateOnly="True" runat="server" />

DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DueDate"]);
((TextBox)(dtdueDate.Controls[0])).Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dtdueDate.LocalId` property for formatting date, here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol.localeid.aspx) and [Locale IDs, Input Locales, and Language Collections for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx) or create your own DatePicker Control, read here: [SharePoint DateTime Control Date Format](http://technucleus.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-datetime-control-date-format.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
dtdueDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DueDate"] == null ? null : item["DueDate"].ToString());
```